# I have a script that automatically copies form submissions to a new sheet. I need to trim the white noise before automatic copy

Tags: google-apps-script

From form submission I have a script that copies each row to another sheet. I have discovered that if you submit something with an inadvertent space before or after AKA whitespace it can make other functions not work properly. I looked up .trim() but am unsure how to implement this into my code. could somebody show me how to do this with my current script

```
function getNextIndexA() {
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Working");
var myValues = sheetTo.getRange('A:A').getValues();
var i;
for (i=0; i<myValues.length; i++) {
if (myValues[i][0] === '')
return i+1;
}
return i+1;
}

function onFormSubmit(event){
var ss = event.source;
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = 7;
var pageSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Working');
var target = pageSheet.getRange(getNextIndexA(), 1, 1, 7);
s.getRange(row, 2, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

[image: Sheet screenshot]

A bit more code to show.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  moveRowByCheckboxToSomeSheet_(e);
}

function moveRowByCheckboxToSomeSheet_(e) {
  const numColumnsToMove = 8;
  let sheet;
  if (e.value !== 'TRUE'
    || e.range.columnStart !== 10
    || !(sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(/^(Working)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  e.range.setValue(false);
  const targetSheetName = e.range.offset(0, -1).getDisplayValue();
  const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍ㅤㅤ⚠️ㅤATTENTIONㅤ⚠️", "ㅤAre you sure you want to move this row?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response !== SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
    return;
  }
  //findEmailAddress();
  const rangeToMove = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumnsToMove);
  const values = rangeToMove.getValues();
  appendRows_(targetSheet, values, 1);
  var nv = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, numColumnsToMove + 2).setValue(null);
}

function appendRows_(sheet, data, optColumn) {
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
    data = [[data]];
  } else if (!Array.isArray(data[0])) {
    data = [data];
  }
  const rowStart = getLastRow_(sheet, optColumn) + 1;
  const columnStart = Number(optColumn) || 1;
  const numRows = data.length;
  const numColumns = data[0].length;
  const range = sheet.getRange(rowStart, columnStart, numRows, numColumns);
  range.setValues(data);
  return { range: range, rowStart: rowStart, columnStart: columnStart, numRows: numRows, numColumns: numColumns };
}

function getLastRow_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  const values = columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1).getDisplayValues()
      : sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  for (var row = values.length - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    if (values[row].join('')) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return row + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  e.values.shift();
  var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName('Working');
 tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 2, 1, e.values.length).setValues(e.values)
}
```

Comment: I am unclear how this will still allow me to copy my data to the working sheet. Please explain.

Comment: It is designed to do it when you linked sheet receives a form Submission.  You must also create an installable trigger name onFormSubmit(e) and it must be the only function with that name.

Comment: I should have clarified. I have multiple GAS scripts and I already have an onformsubmit with installable trigger. so adding this one will not work.

Comment: Then you will have to discriminate between the forms by using e.range.getSheet() because each form writes to a different sheet.  When I use the term sheet I mean an objrect of [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).  I often create an object with sheet names as properties and pointers to functions as values

Comment: I'm lost with your answer. The sheet name of the form responses is "Form Responses" the submissions automatically copy from there to "Working" sheet so I can then add some data to each row and copy them to other sheets. I am trying trim the leading/trailing whitespace after each new submission is automatically copied to the "Working" sheet.

Comment: Could something like this work?

function onEdit(e) {
var tsh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Working");
var trim = ths.trimWhitespace();
 tsh.getRange('A3:G2500').setValues(trim);
  moveRowByCheckboxToSomeSheet_(e);
}

Comment: Actually I think you may wish to simply replace your onFormSubmit with this solution.

Comment: Still not able to get to the bottom of this. I am not getting it I guess

Comment: Can share an image of your working sheet ?

Comment: I need more information to help you.

Comment: Original post updated